# Windows Phone Creates hyperlink out of nowhere

Tags: email

in some emails on my window phone 8  - a hyperlink mysteriously appears where none should be. the link connects to an empty website.  How can I make this stop happening?

Comment: An example might help us figure out what's going on.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or provide a little more detail?

Answer (score 2):

The email app automatically tries to detect hyperlinks. Android and iPhones do this as well. There are instances where each of these incorrectly try to place a link where none belongs. I believe this is the case here.